# Specflow 3.1 + .NET core Visual studio mac does not show feature files nor does it understand the gherkin

Tags: macos, .net-core, specflow, visual-studio-mac

I'm trying to setup a .NET core (3.1) test project on Visual Studio (8.4.7) with Specflow (3.1) on my Mac. I have added the Specflow extension to VS and for the NuGet packages, have added Specflow, Specflow.MsTest, Specflow.NetCore and Specflow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation (and some other packages). However, Visual Studio does not recognize the gherkin in the feature file nor does it show the feature file in the solution explorer, only the code behind feature.cs file. I have tried many things but can't seem to get this to show.

I did try doing the same steps in Windows and it seems to work just fine, I cannot find any bugs logged for this so I'm wondering if there is something different that needs to be configured for Mac.

[image: Visual Studio MacOS]

Comment: Silly question, but have you closed all visual studio windoes so the extension could finish installing? Do you have more than one version of visual studio installed?

Comment: I only have one version installed and I have let the extension install fully, I even tried installing from file since you can download the extension from their github.